# Kivy: memory leaks on my 'Game of life' code

Tags: python, memory-leaks, kivy, conways-game-of-life

I'm new on Kivy.

I'm writing a classic Game of life with some more interaction. My Python code is working except that is leaking memory! It's really annoying because I just use the same twin structure for any next generation's result, so I do not expect that it is growing up! This is my code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

import random

class UnlifeGame(Widget):
    colors = {0: [0, 0, 0], 1: [1, .8, .2], 10: [.2, .8, .2]}
    testing=0
    cells=[]

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        x1st = int((touch.x - 14) / 12)
        y1st = int((touch.y - 14) / 12)
        for xSquad in range(x1st, x1st + 2):
            if xSquad >= len(self.cells):
                xSquad = 0
            for ySquad in range(y1st, y1st + 2):
                if ySquad >= len(self.cells[0]):
                    ySquad = 0
                self.cells[xSquad][ySquad][self.testing] = 10
                with self.canvas:
                    Color(self.colors[10][0], self.colors[10][1], self.colors[10][2])
                    Rectangle(pos=(12+xSquad*12, 12+ySquad*12), size=(10, 10))

    def update(self, dt):
        if len(self.cells) == 0:
            with self.canvas:
                # set to Amber color
                Color(1, .8, .2)
                for xx in range(0, (self.width-14)/12):
                    self.cells.append([])
                    for yy in range(0, (self.height-14)/12):
                        # Add a cell holder
                        self.cells[xx].append([int(random.randint(0,2) == 0), 0])
                        if self.cells[xx][yy][0] == 1:
                            Rectangle(pos=(12+xx*12, 12+yy*12), size=(10, 10))
            return

        nextgen = int(self.testing == 0)
        for xx in range(0, len(self.cells)):
            for yy in range(0, len(self.cells[xx])):
                neigh = bool(self.cells[xx][yy][self.testing]) * -1 # Do not count itself!
                zombies = 0
                for nx in range(xx-1, xx+2):
                    if nx >= len(self.cells):
                        nx = 0
                    for ny in range(yy-1, yy+2):
                        if ny >= len(self.cells[xx]):
                            ny = 0
                        neigh += bool(self.cells[nx][ny][self.testing]);
                        zombies += int(self.cells[nx][ny][self.testing] / 10)
                if neigh < 2 or neigh > 3:
                    # DEATH
                    self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen] = 0
                elif neigh == 2 and self.cells[xx][yy][self.testing] == 0:
                    # NO SPAWN
                    self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen] = 0
                elif zombies >= 2:
                    # UNLIFE
                    self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen] = 10
                else:
                    # LIFE
                    self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen] = 1
                if self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen] != self.cells[xx][yy][self.testing]:
                    # Something is changed 
                    with self.canvas:
                        # set to Green, Amber OR black color
                        Color(self.colors[self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen]][0], self.colors[self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen]][1], self.colors[self.cells[xx][yy][nextgen]][2])
                        Rectangle(pos=(12+xx*12, 12+yy*12), size=(10, 10))
        self.testing = int(self.testing == 0)

class UnlifeApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = UnlifeGame()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 0.5)
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UnlifeApp().run()
```

The only object that maybe I need to unset will be the Rectangle that I draw on the canvas. But I'm not sure that it will be useful, because I think that it will be just drawn by canvas and disposed. But, if it isn't, how can I reach the obsolete ones to remove them, into canvas?

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it's leaking memory? Are you sure? Can you include your measurements? Over what time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your canvas code is incredibly inefficient - every time the game changes, you add new Color and Rectangle instructions to the canvas without removing the old ones, so you're effectively drawing an increasingly large number of rectangles *behind* everything else. I guess this is the cause of what you call a memory leak.

It would be much better to draw all the rectangles just once, but keep references to the graphics objects and *update* them instead of drawing on top. This is very efficient, both in Python (you only make all the objects once) and in the graphics layer (you just change some parameters of existing graphics objects, without adding new ones to process).

The basic way to do this is

```
with self.canvas:
    self.color = Color(...)
    self.rectangle = Rectangle(...)
```

Then later you can do `self.color.rgba = [1, 0, 0, 1]` for red (or similarly for all the other properties of `Color`), or something like `self.rectangle.pos = (10, 10)` to update that. In your case, you'd not want single references, but could store a list of references to all the colours and all you have to do is update the right one. You don't need to change the `Rectangle`s at all, since their colours are the only thing changing.